# Please, explain what n_splits actually mean in sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to split data for train and test controlling the groups, so I'm using

```
sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit
```

However I don't quite understand the parameter **n_splits**.

My code looks like this:

```
gs = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, train_size=.7, random_state=42)
train_ix, val_ix = next(gs.split(X_new, y, groups=X_new.subjectid))
```

It doesn't matter what number I'm choosing for splits, I will have the datasets of the same size (as I specify in **train_size**). Could you please explain what **n_splits** influences?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n_split` is the number of re-shuffling & splitting iterations while `train_size` specify the size of your training set.

This means that in your case, `GroupShuffleSplit` will generate 10 different train/test set splits with a 70/30 proportion.

Comment: Thank you! So more iterations mean better randomization, is it correct?

Comment: Not, The benefit of using multiple split is to train multiple models and ensure that your algorithm generalize well (if it perform well independently from the splits).